# Elasticsearch Function Score Feature in PHP Client Library

Tags: php, function, elasticsearch

I want to implement function_score to manipulate results in my elastic query. Below is my code. I'm getting this error.

> Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [function_score].","line":1,"col":19}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [function_score].","line":1,"col":19},"status":400}**

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])->build();
$params['index'] = 'providers_wow';

$params['body'] = [
    'function_score' => [
        'query' => [
            'multi_match' => [
                'query' => $_GET['search'],
                'fuzziness' => 2,
                'fields' => ['services', 'specialities', 'full_name', 'primary_speciality']
            ]
        ],
        'score_mode' => 'multiply',
        'functions' => [
            [
                'filter' => [
                    'term' => [
                        'node_type' => 'S'
                    ]
                ],
                'weight' => 4
            ],
            [
                'filter' => [
                    'term' => [
                        'node_type' => 'SP'
                    ]
                ],
                'weight' => 5
            ],
            [
                'filter' => [
                    'term' => [
                        'node_type' => 'P'
                    ]
                ],
                'weight' => 1
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
$params['from'] = 0;
$params['size'] = 100;
$params['_source'] = ["full_name", "services", "specialities", "node_type", "primary_speciality"];

$response = $client->search($params);
```

Comment: function score should be part of query ex query:{ function_score:{}}

Comment: I've tried that ass well. 
    $params['body'] = [
        'query' => [
            'function_score' => [
                'query' => [

Comment: but its not working